# JBoss 5.1.0.GA and huge vfs-nested.tmp

Tags: files, jboss, tmp, java

I noticed this while running a performance test with JMeter. For first half an hour everything was fine and the /server/all/tmp directory size was around 36M.

Then suddenly the tmp directory grew up to 6.1G. The space was taken by jar files inside vfs-nested.tmp. If I let the server sit idle there is no such behaviour.

I found https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JBAS-7126 but adding that config made no difference.

Edit:
Starting up with -Djboss.vfs.forceCopy=false does not create such directory at all. But does that affect clustered setup somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some discussion:
https://community.jboss.org/thread/150212

Deployment using MainDeployer seems to be the cause as this problem did not happen when deploying exploded ear manually in to the server/all/deploy.